# What is "http://init-p01st.push.apple.com"?

Tags: macos, internet, apns

Ive seen this popup a few times in my internet tracking. So, what is Apple using this url for? What happens if I block it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a server used for push notifications for iOS and OS X. If you block it, you may not receive push notifications.

Comment: what about the `/bag`? `http://init-p01st.push.apple.com/bag`

Comment: @AfrizaNArief what about it?

Comment: also for push notification?

Comment: The whole server is to do with push notifications, hence why it has "push" in the name.